# How to read twitter public time using Silverlight 4.0

Tags: silverlight-4.0, twitter, c#-4.0

Can anyone who can give me a step by step instruction on downloading my twitter public time line using Silverlight 4.0?

I already have a consumer key, consumer secret, token and token secret.

Thank you in advance/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [LinqToTwitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/) library. It is quite scenarios complete and it lets you query Twitter in Linq style.

Comment: Do you have a test sample application? I'm really having a hard time implementing those API. Thank you

Comment: LinqToTwitter has complete documentation on codeplex http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Making%20API%20Calls. In your case you want to check your (particular user) public timeline. Here is the link for the same http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Querying%20the%20User%20Timeline&referringTitle=Making%20Status%20Queries%20and%20Calls. Believe me I used the code provided in documentation and it works. I did not do anything specific.

Comment: Why is when I reference and build it, it has an error Error    8    The type or namespace name 'LinqToTwitter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    C:\LinqToTwitter_v2.0.12\LinqToTwitter\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs    9    7    WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: By the error that you have posted, I am guessing that you are trying to run some sample application that came with LinqToTwitter. Try creating your own sample app. In my app all I have done is a reference to LinqToTwitter and to System.Xml.Linq dll.

Comment: I created my own app using Visual Studio 2010, I initialized TwitterContext, hit F5, error comes. You can view my screenshots here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1719731/Untitled.png. Thank you

Comment: I replicated your problem. Basically you created a Windows application in VS2010. By default target framework of windows applications in VS2010 is .Net Framework 4 Client Profile. LinqToTwitter library is somehow dependent on "System.ServiceModel.Web" dll which is not part of .net 4.0 client profile. Go to project properties and switch to target framework as .Net Framework 4. That should solve the issue. Happy coding. :)

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for your big help. I've been working on this since yesterday. Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

im sure Twitter has an API. Go download it, read its documentation.
The best case scenario is if twitter exposes a web service. then things would be trivial implementing it in SL 4.